# Trapping gestures in a UIView

Tags: iphone, uiview, gestures

This seems simple enough, but I'm stuck.

I have a View Controller that respondes to some gestures.
I add a subview that is like a "heads up" menu; it covers the entire screen, the background color is semi-transparent so faint images of other views below show through.

I don't want the "heads up" subview to let gestures pass to the parent viewcontroller. That is, I don't want the VC to be gesture-sensitive until the "Heads up" subview is dismissed.

Now, the VC acts on gestures even when the "heads up" subview is displayed.

Thanx in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone is interested...
I ended up building a custom view that I uses as a "gesture trap" where needed.
Not very pretty, but works fine.